# Find matching string in list and only keep the matching string

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I have a list in R with multiple strings that I need to match with my column in a data frame and keep only the matching strings.

```
list <- c('Ford', 'Toyota', 'BMW')

Col1         Col2         
1            Ford A1
2            Toyota Prius
3            BMW B2
4            Ford A2
5            Tesla T1
```

So I want to match Col2 with list and then change the data to:

```
Col1         Col2         
1            Ford
2            Toyota
3            BMW
4            Ford
5            Tesla T1
```

Comment: How is this related to rstudio?

Comment: Done. Now... show your effort/code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your list to create a regex string, which can then be used in a `sub` call:

```
regex.string <- paste0( ".*(", paste( list, collapse = "|" ), ").*" )
```

This makes the string:

```
> regex.string
[1] ".*(Ford|Toyota|BMW).*"
```

Now use that in a sub call:

```
df$Col2 <- sub( regex.string, "\\1", df$Col2 )
```

So the regex looks for any value contained in `list`, if it's found, it replaces the entire text value with what was found.

Result:

```
> df
  Col1     Col2
1    1     Ford
2    2   Toyota
3    3      BMW
4    4     Ford
5    5 Tesla T1
```

NOTE: as mentioned below, this will likely break for car makes containing special regex characters.

Comment: Does this work if the strings contains special regex characters?

Comment: Probably not, no. Do you have an example?

Comment: Mind you, I imagine that would break something like a `grepl` call as well.